# Uploading documents to Sharepoint with Powershell -

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

The script exports to a CSV and the files need to be uploaded to SharePoint online.

1. The export works perfectly
2. Document is renamed to exclude "@mycompany.com"
3. The error I get is :

Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
At line:46 char:9
+         $Context.ExecuteQuery()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

```
   Get-ChildItem 'c:\users\xxxx\downloads' -Filter *.csv | % {

        $eachFile =Get-ChildItem $Outputfile -Filter *.csv

        $eachFile | ForEach-Object{

        #Upload Variables  - Admin Heidi
        [string]$AdminName = "hxxn@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
        [string]$AdminPassword = "Cxx1"

        #Upload Credentials 
        [SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $AdminPassword -AsPlainText -Force 
        $credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminName, $(convertto-securestring $AdminPassword -asplaintext -force)
        $AdminSiteURL="https://nrcl.sharepoint.com"

        #Site report will be stored on SharePoint
        $SiteURL="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/nrg/"
        $LibraryName="Audit History"

        #Set up the context
        $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Context.Credentials = $Credentials

        #Get the Library
        $Library =  $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName)

        #Get the file from c:/
        $FileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $OutputFile)).OpenRead()

        #Get File Name from source file path
        $SourceFileName = Split-path $eachFile -leaf

         #sharepoint online upload file powershell
        $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
        $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
        $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
        $FileCreationInfo.URL = $SourceFileName
        $FileUploaded = $Library.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)

        #powershell upload single file to sharepoint online
        $Context.Load($FileUploaded)
#######--------fails after this line  ---------------#####
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()

        #Close file stream
        $FileStream.Close()

        write-host "File has been uploaded!"

        }
```

Comment: remove "+ "/" + $File.Name"  The first parameter should be a URL.  ".name" needs to be .fullname.  The line would be   $webclient.UploadFile($destination, "PUT", $File.Fullname)  Goto: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile?view=netcore-3.1  and search for "public byte[] UploadFile (string address, string method, string fileName);"

Comment: $File =Get-ChildItem  "c:\users\my name\downloads\" will have more that one file in it.  You will need to loop though each file to upload the files.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron.  Made the changes you suggested. We have a new error. 

ForEach-Object : Exception calling "UploadFile" with "3" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
At C:\Users\Heidi Goosen\Documents\National Resources Group\Script original - full functional.ps1:37 char:33
+ $result | Group-Object UserId | ForEach-Object {
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ForEach-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand

Comment: Can you open ` "https://https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Dynamics365/Reports"` with a web browser.

Comment: Can you update your example with the new changes?

Comment: @Aaron Ive changed the approach, but am still unable to this to upload as expected.